# Download tar file using Axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an API-endpoint that gives me a tar file with the `Content-Type: application/x-tar`, which is then being served to my frontend app using Express. I tried fetching this file using Axios with the `responseType: 'blob'` but I cannot open the binary without an error saying that's in an unsupported format.
Here is what I'm trying:

```
// backend
const axiosRes = await axios.get(`${API}/file`,
    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-tar' }, responseType: 'blob' }
  );
res.send({ data: axiosRes.data });

// frontend
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.tar');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

How can I get the file in real .tar format and send it to the frontend?

Comment: The content-type **request** header describes your **request** body. Since you don't have one, you don't need the header

Comment: It's not super clear from your question but does your backend make a request to another API for the file? If so, how does your frontend make the request to your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem #1** - Axios only supports `responseType: "blob"` in the browser.

If your Express app needs to retrieve a binary file, use this

```js
const axiosRes = await axios.get(`${API}/file`, {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }, // no data, no content-type
  responseType: "arraybuffer", // use instead of "blob"
});
```

**Problem #2** - You are responding with JSON

Using this

> ```js
> res.send({ data: axiosRes.data });
> ```

will try and JSON stringify the binary file response which simply won't work. Instead, just send the raw response data

```js
res.type(axiosRes.headers["content-type"]).send(axiosRes.data);
```